# Where to look for logic level of a circuit in the datasheet?

Tags: logic-level, documentation

Whenever I pick a chip for my project, I run through the same chore: finding out if its logic levels match what I work with. Is it 5V? 3.3V? 1.3V? Or one of these that sources whatever level I apply to VCC and reads anything from 0.6V to 36V and more just fine?

I'm fairly sure that information is supposed to be in the datasheet but only rarely I manage to find it somewhere in clear view. Common search for "Logic" turns up only irrelevant entries; search for Voltage brings hundreds of various ratings, levels, tolerances etc. I usually end up looking up a circuit involving given chip.

What are the usual entries/clues/symbols to look for in a datasheet to find the logic levels of given circuit?

Comment: I don't recall having problems finding this information in a real datasheet.  Give us links to examples.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: I still have no clue what levels this [PSoC4 development board](http://www.cypress.com/?rID=92146) uses...

Comment: That's not a datasheet.  Get the datasheet for the chip used by that development board, and the logic levels should be clearly specified in there.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Found it. [datasheet](http://www.cypress.com/?docID=46322) Third page of Electrical Specifications, sixth table,  V_IH - Input voltage high threshold, and V_IL - Input voltage low threshold. I'm completely sure I'd either miss it or spend at least another half an hour looking for it if not for Majenko's answer.

Comment: That's actually a pretty clear datasheet.  In this one, you scan down the "Description" column and find "Input high threshold" and "Input low threshold" right at the top of page 16.  They do use the common Vih and Vil symbols, but you don't need to know those previously to understand the spec.  They define their terms, like any good datasheet does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are usually 4 values you need to find:

- \$V_{IL}\$ and \$V_{IH}\$

These are the input logic levels.  They are often listed as a proportion of the supply voltage, such as \$V_{IH} = 0.6 V_{DD}\$, which is 0.6 times the supply voltage (so for 5V that would be 3V).  The low voltage must be below \$V_{IL}\$ and the high above \$V_{IH}\$.

- \$V_{OL}\$ and \$V_{OH}\$

These are the output voltage levels.  They are listed as maximum and minimum values respectively.  Again, they may be listed as a proportion of the supply voltage.

Comment: That's part of it.  But also the maximum allowable voltages on a pin (and typically the supplies, too - often but not always they are closely related).

Answer (score 2):

This is not something I would use a search function to find.  Datasheets tend to have all electrical specs in one section.  For large datasheets with 100s of pages (like a microcontroller), there will be something like a "electrical characteristics" chapter.  For more normal smaller datasheets, like for a individual logic chip, that section will be obvious and usually after the initial maketing babble on the front page.

The logic level thresholds really should not be hard to find in any reasonable datasheet.  If they are truly missing, then you probably don't have the real datasheet.  You may have a abbreviated "sell sheet", a half-assed translation from chinese with information missing, or from a less than scrupulous vendor.  In those cases, unless you really really need that particular part, go find one that is proplerly specified.

Here is the applicable snippet from the datasheet you have now posted a link to:

[image]

This appears to be a well written datasheet, as one would expect from a major company like Cypress.  This snippet is from the top of page 16.  They do use the common names of V<sub>IH</sub> and V<sub>IL</sub>, but you don't need to assume what those mean.  To find a particular parameter, scan down the *Description* column until you get to what you are looking for.  In this case they use *Input voltage high threshold* and *Input voltage low threshold* to describe the parameters in words, which are then also the definition of V<sub>IH</sub> and V<sub>IL</sub>.  I don't see how they could have made this any clearer.

Comment: Often there are only abbreviated names of the values given, and the electrical characteristics sometimes runs several pages long, so even if these informations are in plain view, they are simply buried in the bulk of ratings, tolerances, timings etc. - finding them can be hard if I don't know the keywords to look for.

Comment: @SF.: No, usually not hard, although you do have to actually *look* at the list.  Read each one and see what it is telling you.  You need to do that anyway, if only to make sure that the other values don't apply to you or are limits in how you plan to use the part.  One trick is to look at the units.  You are looking for Volts, so can ignore anything with units of current, time, etc.  Logic levels are sometimes called Vih (input high), Vil (input low), but don't count on those exact names.  Good datasheets define their terms, if not in words right by the spec, then maybe in a graphs close by.

Comment: For a person skilled in it, sure they are not hard. Take it from a newbie: They are hard to find for a newbie.

Comment: @SF: The effort of diligently going through the lists and tables is what makes one skilled.

Comment: @whatsisname: I guess I have to learn this then.

Comment: What Olin missed is the the question is actually far more basic - to paraphrase, the real question is not "how to find the values" but rather "what are the *names* of the values that should be looked for".  Things that have units of volts are indeed often a clue - but then sometimes the values are stated as a decimal fraction of the relevant IO section's supply voltage.